# console output log with jquery selector gives strange output

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, console.log

When I use jQuery selectors in the Chrome console with a class of container:

```
console.log($('li').closest('.container'));
```

I would expect to have an output of the below

```
<ul class="container>_</ul>
```

However I am getting the following output:

```
(2) [ul.emphasis.container, li.container, prevObject: n.fn.init(8), context: document]
```

How do I get an output of `<ul class="container>_</ul>`

Comment: `console.log($('li').closest('.container').prop('outerHTML'))`

Comment: It's because you're seeing the jQuery object returned from the selector. This is entirely normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery always returns a custom object containing the underlying native DOM node and all the custom methods jQuery brings with it.

The result in the console is exactly what a jQuery object looks like.

If you wanted the native DOM node, you can use [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
console.log( $('li').closest('.container').get(0) );
```

would get you the underlying DOM node for the first element in the jQuery collection

If you want the HTML returned, you can use

```
$('li').closest('.container').get(0).outerHTML; // outer HTML
$('li').closest('.container').html();           // inner HTML
```

Comment: Or even `$('li').closest('.container')[0]`?